# Android Facebook App links with https scheme

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, applinks

In our project, we have deep links already set up to handle our domain with HTTPS and HTTP schemes.

Everything worked fine until we checked Facebook. They use their own App Links. We implemented those all according to official Guide and Documentation, yet App Links still don't work - links, that should be handled by our apps are opened in Facebook app's CustomTabsManager.

What could be the reason, is it https scheme or is there some secret to handling those?

Comment: Have you verified the additional markup you added via the Facebook debug tool? (And/or used that to clear the cache for the URLs in question, if they are already “known” to Facebook, but did not contain the app link data earlier.)

Comment: Just did it - for Android everything looks fine - no errors, it detected all 3 additional tags.